# Sometimes ubuntu takes 2 minutes to start

Tags: 11.10, boot, tablet, dmesg

Sorry for the English mistakes, I'm Spanish.

I have a tablet with ubuntu 11.10 completely updated. Sometimes it takes about 35 seconds to boot, I suppose it's a right time.

However, there are LOTS of times which takes about 2 minutes. The screen is black about 100 sconds without any message. Unfortunately this happens very often and randomly: maybe there are 3 wrong times, then 1 right one, 8 wrong, 3 right, 1 wrong, 2 right... No pattern at all.

I copy the results of dmesg command in a 'good' and 'bad' boot:

- Good boot (about 35 seconds): http://pastie.org/3186757
- Wrong boot (about 120 seconds) http://pastie.org/3186449

EDIT: Thanks to Rinzwind and JanC,I've investigated and the booting issue appears always at the same point:

[ less than 1 second] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
[ 98 seconds before] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64

---

Hola, poseo una tableta con ubuntu 11.10 completamente actualizado. En ocasiones tarda 35 segundos en arrancar, imagino que es un tiempo normal de arranque.

Sin embargo MUY a menudo tarda 2 minutos en arrancar. Después de encender la tableta la pantalla se queda negra durante aproximadamente 100 segundos. Por desgracia esto ocurre muy a menudo y de forma aleatoria: por ejemplo 3 arranques malos, 1 bueno, 8 malos, 3 buenos, 1 malo, 2 buenos... No sigue ningún patrón.

Copio los resultados del comando dmesg en un arranque 'bueno' y uno 'malo':

- Arranque bueno (unos 35 segundos): http://pastie.org/3186757
- Arranque malo (unos 120 segundos) http://pastie.org/3186449

EDITO: Gracias a Rinzwind y JanC, he investigado y el error aparece siempre en el mismo sitio:

[ less than 1 second] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
[ 98 seconds before] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64

Comment: Install `bootchart` and compare a normal boot with a long boot! it will 100% tell you what file is causing it and thus what service.

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like there might be an issue with "booting" the graphics device (0.5 seconds on a good boot, 98 second on a bad one).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the information with bootcharts results in my previous message. Can you help me?

Comment: A kernel update solved the problem.

Comment: Congrats on solving the problem, can you please write a answer your question instead of editing it? Thanks. :)

Comment: @jrg Sure, I've just post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidLópez no, *thank you*! Glad you're no longer having this problem! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The iso I used to install ubuntu was not the 'official' release, it was made by a company to adapt Canonical's to tablets. The modified iso blocked kernel updates: I remove the blocking, I update to kernel 3.0.0-16 and the problem dissapear.

---

He resuelto el problema. La iso que usé para instalar ubuntu no era la oficial, sino una modificada por una empresa para adaptarla a la tableta. Esta iso modificada impedía las actualizaciones del kernel: eliminé ese bloqueo, actualicé al kernel 3.0.0-16 y se solucionó el problema.